# How can i get nerd fonts in kitty terminal

Tags: void-linux, kitty

i can't get beautiful font of codding in terminal:
[image: firacode]
i am reading [documentation of fonts](https://docs.voidlinux.org/config/graphical-session/fonts.html) in voidlinux.org
and i'm installing alacritty and kitty and st , but not work
my conf of alacritty is:

```
font:
  normal:
    family: Fira Code
    style: Medium
  bold:
    family: Fira Code
    style: SemiBold
  italic:
    family: Fira Code
    style: Light
  size: 10
```

but if i'm try to use this symbols and font : it's not work:
[image]

- my font now is:

```
$ fc-list | grep -i "fira"|awk -F: '{print $2}' |sort|uniq

 Fira Code
 Fira Code,Fira Code Light
 Fira Code,Fira Code Medium
 Fira Code,Fira Code Retina
 Fira Code,Fira Code SemiBold
 FiraCode Nerd Font
 FiraCode Nerd Font Mono
 FiraMono Nerd Font
 FiraMono Nerd Font Mono
```

Comment: IMHO, code typeset in symbols that aren't typed as is is just distracting.

Answer (score 2):

The name of the font isn't `Fira Code`, it's `'Fira Code Regular Nerd Font Complete Mono'`; use with the single quotation mark.

Comment: not worked yet , because i'm not have this font as this string , i'm add my font that have now in at the end of my question

Comment: so, did you try with one of the fonts you actually have, in quotation marks?

Comment: yes: i'm try lot of time , because i want this font , it's wonderful, but i can't get it know, void Linux is fast but you must config every thing manually

Comment: all Linuxes are equally fast (it's basically the same operating system). The distro has little influence on it. Maybe your choice of desktop environment has. Also, the font choice in alacritty has no other way than manual configuration, that's also the same on all distros. If you chose, say, gnome-terminal instead of alacritty, that would come with a settings dialog.